# PHP Sort DOM Element and Replace

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I currently have a ul list that looks like this:

```
<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li class="navButton" id="amps_off_button" data-order="6">
        <span class="navButton-color red"><p>AMPS Off</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="amps_alarms" data-order="7">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>AMPS Alarms</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="sysConfig" data-order="3">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>System Configuration</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span></li>
    <li class="navButton" id="system" data-order="4">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>System</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="backBtn" data-order="100">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>BACK</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="rescan" data-order="101">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>ReScan</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my Navigation class, I have a function that can be called that will sort the order of the unordered list by the value in data-order:

```
public function setOrder() {
    $liNodeList = $this->xpath->query("//ul[@id='primary-nav']//li");
    $liNodes = iterator_to_array($liNodeList);

    usort($liNodes, array('Navigation', 'sortListByOrderAttr'));

    if ($liNodeList->length == count($liNodes)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $liNodeList->length; $i++) {
            $node = $liNodeList->item($i);
            $newNode = $liNodes[$i];
            $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
        }
    }
    else echo "error";
}

private static function sortListByOrderAttr($a, $b) {
    return (int) $a->getAttribute('data-order') - (int) $b->getAttribute('data-order');
}
```

For some reason, I am not getting the correct order of the list. Instead, the output shows 4 items instead of the 6 items it's supposed to show:

```
<ul id="primary-nav">
    <li class="navButton" id="amps_off_button" data-order="6">
        <span class="navButton-color red"><p>AMPS Off</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="amps_alarms" data-order="7">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>AMPS Alarms</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="backBtn" data-order="100">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>BACK</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="navButton" id="rescan" data-order="101">
        <span class="navButton-color"><p>ReScan</p></span>
        <span class="glare"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I suspect my problem here is that my `$node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);` is no es bueno. Maybe I need a different approach to sort this? Help appreciated!

Comment: What do you think `replaceChild` does?

Comment: Not sure if you're being sarcastic or for real.

Comment: I'm being real. Well, Socratically real.

Comment: `replaceChild` replaces an old node with a new node. `$liNodes` maintains the node configuration. I would think a `replaceChild` would work flawlessly.

Comment: And what happens to the old node when you replace it?

Comment: Old node is returned. Hah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after thinking about what cHao was saying, it appears that after re-reading how `replaceChild` works, it explains why my method didn't yield the correct result, due to the new child nodes already existed in the node set.

I've fixed the code as such:

```
public function setOrder() {
    $liNodeList = $this->xpath->query("//ul[@id='primary-nav']//li");
    $liNodes = iterator_to_array($liNodeList);

    usort($liNodes, array('Navigation', 'sortListByOrderAttr'));

    if ($liNodeList->length == count($liNodes)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $liNodeList->length; $i++) {
            $node = $liNodeList->item($i);
            $newNode = $this->doc->importNode($liNodes[$i], TRUE);
            $node->parentNode->appendChild($newNode);
        }
    }
    else echo "error with nav menu";
}
```